# Building App using maven

Tags: java, android, maven

While building Android APP using maven I am getting exception below

```
> [ERROR] Cannot add resources from
> ~/.m2/repository/com/inmobi/androidsdk/AdNetwork/3.5.4/AdNetwork-3.5.4.jar
> com.android.sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files at
> the same path inside the APK  at
> com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder$JavaAndNativeResourceFilter.checkEntry(ApkBuilder.java:125)
>   at
> com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeZip(SignedJarBuilder.java:228)
>   at
> com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.addResourcesFromJar(ApkBuilder.java:576)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkBuilder.addResourcesFromJar(ApkBuilder.java:292)
>   at
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.doAPKWithAPKBuilder(ApkMojo.java:586)
>   at
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.createApkFile(ApkMojo.java:356)
>   at
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.execute(ApkMojo.java:307)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I have added the sdk jar(AdNetwork-3.5.4.jar) to my local repository and added the dependency in my pom

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem has nothing with repository/dependency to do

```
com.android.sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK at

 com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder$JavaAndNativeResourceFilter.checkEntry(ApkBuilder.java:125)
```

I suspect the line above to be the problem. Please look there to see if there is nothing wrong or **duplicated**

Answer (score 0):

In your maven-android-plugin try adding:

```
<extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-android-developers/QjbzoaC1Q3k)

Comment: I have added the above line in my pom but the problem still persists. 
 <plugin>
                                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<manifest>
<debuggable>true</debuggable>
</manifest>
<extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
</configuration>
<extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>

Comment: As I am newbie I am stuck with this problem from so many days .
In this big Android World no one is there to solve this issue .